# UWP - InvalidCastException when accessing ProductListing.CurrencyCode

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I'm facing a really weird issue.
I need to store the `CurrencyCode` property of a `ProductListing` item in an WSA_10_0 environment.

Here is the code

```
foreach (ProductListing product in listings.ProductListings.Values)
{
    Debug.Log("CURRENCY_CODE/"+product.CurrencyCode);
}
```

When trying to execute the code I get the following error

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.ProductListing' to type
>   'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.IProductListing2'.

Now, this is really weird because [as this documentation page states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlisting) `ProductListing` objects inherit from `IProductListing2`.

The entire exception content is here

```
System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.ProductListing' to type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.IProductListing2'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)
       at Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.ProductListing.get_CurrencyCode()
       at CI.WSANative.IAPStore.WSANativeStore.<GetProductListingsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

---

UPDATE:

I've tried accessing the `CurrencyCode` property of the listings object, which is of type `ListingInformation` and despite it is supposed to have that property, [basing on the class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.listinginformation), it gives a similar error.

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.ListingInformation' to type
>   'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.IListingInformation2'.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are `casting`?

Comment: That's the point, I'm not casting anything.
There seems to be some implicit casting going on, as if it couldn't find the CurrencyCode property inside of the object type

Comment: Could you remove your `.Values` in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: I think this is irrelevant, as I just found out that the listings object, of type `ListingInformation` also has a CurrencyCode property and it fails in the same exact way.

`Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.ListingInformation' to type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.IListingInformation2'.`

I'm starting to think it might be related to an API mismatch of some sort

Comment: What is the return type of `listings.ProductListings.Values`?

Comment: ProductListings is a `IMapView<string, ProductListing>`, so ProductListings.Values is a `ProductListing[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CurrencyCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.listinginformation) property, along with IListingInformation2 interface were introduced on Windows version 10586. If you build your application against 10586 or newer SDK, you will be able to use it in your code, but if you run the application on a machine with Windows version 10240, CLR will still attempt to call that method by first doing a query interface on your Windows Runtime object for the interface that property getter is on (in CurrencyCode case, it's IListingInformation2), but the query interface call will fail, and CLR will throw an InvalidCastException.

Comment: So the UWP is not so universal after all ... Do I have to assume it is not safe to use that property at all?

In the end I made a workaround to get the CurrencyCode from RegionInfo instead of  ListingInformation.
Are you aware of any edge cases where this approach might fail?
Is there any other way to access that information in a more reliable way?

Comment: Well... you have several options: 1) Detect failure condition and somehow have a fallback plan; 2) Specify minimum supported windows version to be 10586 in your AppX manifest; 3) Don't use that API.

Comment: @SergioBonfiglio Did this solution work for you? I have encountered the same problem, but raising the minimum SDK version did not resolve it for me.

Comment: @Joseph I believe so, it's been long and I've since then changed project and company. I'm afraid I can't give any more specific help.