# Parse currency with custom store region

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

### Problem outline

I need to get the numeric value for the price of a purchased product, in order to do so I need to parse the `FormattedPrice` received from the `ProductListing` object I receive, [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlisting).

The problem here is that I need to consider all of the edge cases, for instance the case where the user is located in a foreign country, has the system running with that locale but sets up the store to receive content from his home region.

For instance I currently set my pc (GB region, GB system language) to **receive content from the Italian store**, so I receive prices in euros and with the comma as separator for decimals, but when I try to determine my current location with either `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` **it always returns GB**, so it will always fail to parse as it will interpret Italian prices with a GB NumberFormat setup.
[image: Store region is different from actual system region]

Since I need to initialise a CultureInfo object related to the store region is there a way to retrieve this information via code?

Thanks.

---

### Things I've already tried

:

- [Using the currency code provided by StoreListing/ProductListing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678462/uwp-invalidcastexception-when-accessing-productlisting-currencycode)
- Using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, it returns GB no matter what
- Using `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`, it returns GB no matter what
- Using `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion`, it returns GB no matter what
- [Looking at the UWP Globalization documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization)
- [Looking at the UWP Store documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store)

Comment: Not sure I understand from your question, do you have name of the culture in which price was formatted?

Comment: No, I cannot retrieve any info about the store region, thus I cannot initialise a CultureInfo object for that specific region.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you run this code on user device or on server?

Comment: Regardless of the formatting issue, you must keep in mind the exchange rate between the currencies; 1 pound may or may not equal 1 euro, and it changes daily

Comment: @andriiLitvinov I run this on device

Comment: @MadMyche I don't have to make any conversion, I just have to parse some currency string to a float variable

Comment: Store Region is not needed, your linked documentation shows that `CurrencyCode` is an available property, and that corresponds to a `NumberFormatInfo` so you can parse it.

Comment: I've already tried using the CurrencyCode property, as I say in the bottom section.
I've actually linked another question where I tried to find an alternative to it, because it doesn't work below a certain version of Windows10.

Answer (score 3):

That's a problem with the `CultureInfo` class. You should use Win32 API which is  [`GetLocaleInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the `CultureInfo`.

You can do this from *C++* then call it from *C#* or you can do it from *C#* with PInvoke since it already exist on a dll file.

There is no need to re-do this from scratch because [this](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2017/05/03/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp-part-2/) website already made `CultureInfoHelper` wrapper for the [`GetLocaleInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

You use it like this:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfoHelper.GetCurrentCulture();
```

The `CultureInfoHelper` script:

```
public class CultureInfoHelper
{
    [DllImport("api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetLocaleInfoEx(string lpLocaleName, uint LCType, StringBuilder lpLCData, int cchData);

    private const uint LOCALE_SNAME = 0x0000005c;
    private const string LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT = null;
    private const string LOCALE_NAME_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = "!x-sys-default-locale";

    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 530;

    public static CultureInfo GetCurrentCulture()
    {
        var name = InvokeGetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNAME);

        if (name == null)
        {
            name = InvokeGetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNAME);

            if (name == null)
            {
                // If system default doesn't work, use invariant
                return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            }
        }

        return new CultureInfo(name);
    }

    private static string InvokeGetLocaleInfoEx(string lpLocaleName, uint LCType)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder(BUFFER_SIZE);

        var resultCode = GetLocaleInfoEx(lpLocaleName, LCType, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

        if (resultCode > 0)
        {
            return buffer.ToString();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unluckily it still returns en-GB.
The store region is still Italy and the prices I'm getting are still in euros, so I need to find a way to get a reference to the store region, not the system culture.

Comment: I thought you wanted to get the region. The one circled in red in your screenshot?

Comment: I do want to get that region, but I've just implemented the solution you provided and it still returns en-GB

Comment: Mine returns the correct value from the settings. What do you expect it to return? Also, what property/variable from `CultureInfo` are you accessing?

Comment: I'm trying to get `NumberFormat`.
As my "Country or Region" field is set to Italy I'm expecting to get IT instead of GB.

Comment: Ok. I will see what else I can do

Comment: Please try `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` and  `CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture`.... Does it still give en-GB?

Comment: So:`CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` is not available on .Net Framework 4.5.
`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` returns en-GB.

Even if the first one was available its description denotes that its behaviour is not the one I'm looking for.